# Can you have control of the DOM with Java as you have it with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am a Javascript Developer and I am planning to learn Java.

So what I am wondering is: are there libraries like jQuery for Java or how do you manipulate the DOM?

**EDIT**

I am not finding libraries. I am asking if is as easy to manipulate the DOM with Java as it is with Javascript.

Comment: Finding libraries is off-topic.

Comment: @nicael I am not finding libraries. I am asking if is as easy to manipulate the DOM with Java as it is with Javascript.

Comment: As above, but Java is a server-side language. Ideally you'd be communicating to the client from Java, where JavaScript would listen to those calls and do DOM manipulation accordingly

Comment: @OwenAyres OK, so as you mentioned, Java should be used as a Backend language and we send the info with Java to the frontend where I have to use Javascript? I thought Java can be used as a frontend language as well.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer It has been customised to aid with app development for platforms like Android, but it is certainly server-side and not intended for client-side web work. From what I have read it is time consuming to try and mash Java into front-end related works. I would strongly advise using it for just the server-side needs and then sending events back to the client for client-side tasks, which would be done in JavaScript.

Comment: Erm... as far as I can tell you would have to use JavaScript anyway to run the Java code client-side.

Comment: What is use case? Question is rather vague. Can find dom parsers for most server side languages

Comment: @charlietfl there is no use case. It is just a general question of the languages. As I want to learn Java, I want to know what can I do and what can't.

Comment: Could have answered this yourself with a google search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are libraries for Java which allow you to manipulate a DOM (which then might be sent to the client / web browser via a HTTP response, or not).

You can use XSL / XPath. This is quite different from jQuery.

It is an interesting question whether there is a server-side library which allows 'jQuery-like' DOM access and manipulation, but this question is off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why off-topic? Is there any other place where I can post it? I just gave you my upvote :P

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score -2):

Don't know exactly what DOM manipulation you need but look at [JSOUP](https://jsoup.org)